# Python- stuck trying to create a "free hand" calculator

Tags: python, int, calculator, equation

I'm trying to create a calculator program in which the user can type an equation and get an answer. I don't want the full code for this, I just need help with a specific part.

The approach I am trying to take is to have the user input the equation as a string (`raw_input`) and then I am trying to convert the numbers from their input to integers. After that I need to know how I can get the operands to do what I want them to do depending on which operand the user uses and where it is in the equation.

What are some methods I might use to accomplish this task?

Here is basically what I have right now:

```
    equation_number = raw_input("\nEnter your equation now: ")
    [int(d) for d in equation_number if d.isdigit()]
```

Those lines are just for collecting input and attempting to convert the numbers into integers.  Unfortunately, it does not seem to be working very well and .isdigit will only work for positive numbers anyway.

Edit- aong152 mentioned recursive parsing, which I looked into, and it appears to have desirable results:

http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-calculator-in-70-python-lines-by-writing-a-recursive-descent-parser/

However, I do not understand the code that the author of this post is using, could anyone familiarize me with the basics of recursive parsing?

Comment: First piece of advice: show how you're **currently trying** to obtain this data and convert it. If you're not there yet, look up how to obtain user input and convert strings to integers.

Comment: By "equation" do you mean an expression to compute like `6 / 2` or really an equation to solve for x, like `2*x = 6`?

Answer (score 1):

The type of program you are trying to make is probably more complicated than you think

The first step would be separating the string into each argument.

Let's say that the user inputs:

1+2.0+3+4

Before you can even convert to ints, you are going to need to split the string up into its components:

- 1
- +
- 2.0
- +
- 3
- +
- 4

This will require a recursive parser, which (seeing as you are new to python) maybe be a bit of a hurdle.

Assuming that you now have each part seperately as strings,

```
float("2.0") = 2.0
int(2.0) = 2
```

Here is a helper function

```
def num (s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except exceptions.ValueError:
        return int(float(s))
```

Comment: Ok, yes, this is what I was looking to do... a recursive parser. Well, I know all of the basics of Python, so I figure the only way to learn anything new is to try something pretty difficult. What exactly is a recursive parser and how is it used? Just a link will be fine if you'd rather not try to explain it.

Comment: I assumed he only wanted to parse ints. aka convert 2.0 into 2, etc.
Obviously if he actually wanted to parse floats, just typecast to float and raise a syntaxError if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `raw_input` just use `input` because `raw_input` returns a string and `input` returns ints

This is a very simple calculator:

```
def calculate():
    x = input("Equation: ")
    print x
while True:
    calculate()
```

the function takes the `input` and prints it then the while loop executes it again

im not sure if this is what you want but here you go and also you should make a way to end the loop

Comment: `input` _evaluates_ the string. This can be problematic if someone chooses to enter something malicious. eg. They could wipe your hard drive, Install a key logger etc.

Answer (score 0):

After using `raw_input()` you can use `eval()` on the result to compute the value of this string.  `eval()` evaluates any valid Python expression and returns the outcome.

But I think this is not to your liking.  You probably want to do more by yourself.

So I think you should have a look at the `re` module to split the input using regular expressions into tokens (sth like numbers and operators).  After this you should write a parser which gets the token stream as input.  You should decide whether this parser shall just return the computed value (e. g. a number) or maybe an abstract syntax tree, i. e. a data structure which represents the expression in an object-oriented (instead of character-oriented) way.  Such an Absy could then be evaluated to get the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with regular expressions?  If not, it's probably a good idea to first learn about them.  They are the weak, non-recursive cousin of parsing.  Don't go deep, just understand the building blocks — A then B, A many times, A or B.

The blog post you found is hard because it implements the parsing by hand.  It's using recursive descent, which is the only way to write a parser by hand and keep your sanity, but it's still tricky.

What people do most of the time is only write a high level *grammar* and use a library (or code generator) to do the hard work of parsing.
Indeed he had an earlier post where he uses a library:
http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-calculator-in-50-python-lines-without-eval/
At least the beginning should be very easy.  Things to pay attention to:

- How precedence arises from the structure of the grammar — `add` consists of `mul`s, not vice versa.
- The moment he adds a rule for parentheses:

  ```
  atom: neg | number | '(' add ')';
  ```

  This is where it really becomes recursive!
- `6-2-1` should parse as (6-2)-1, not 6-(2-1).  He doesn't discuss it, but if you look
  carefully, it also arises from the structure of the grammar.  Don't waste tome on this; just know for future reference that this is called *associativity*.
- The result of parsing is a *tree*.  You can then compute its value in a bottom-up manner.
  In the "Calculating!" chapter he does that, but the in a sort of magic way.
  Don't worry about that.

---

To build a calculator yourself, I suggest you strip the problem as much as possible.

1. Recognizing where numbers end etc. is a bit messy.  It could be part of the grammar, or done by a separate pass called *lexer* or *tokenizer*.
   I suggest you skip it — require the user to type spaces around all operators and parens.  Or just assume you're already given a list of the form `[2.0, "*", "(", 3.0, "+", -1.0, ")"]`.
2. Start with a trivial parser(tokens) function that only handles 3-element expressions — [number, op, number].
   Return a single number, the result of the computation.  (I previously said parsers output a tree which is processed later.  Don't worry about that, returning a number is simpler.)
3. Write a function that expects either a number or parentheses — in the later case it calls parser().

   ```
   >>> number_or_expr([1.0, "rest..."])
   (1.0, ["rest..."])
   >>> number_or_expr(["(", 2.0, "+", 2.0, ")", "rest..."])
   (4.0, ["rest..."])
   ```

   Note that I'm now returning a second value - the remaining part of the input.  Change parser() to also use this convention.
4. Now Rewrite parser() to call number_or_expr() instead of directly assuming tokens[0] and tokens[2] are numbers.
   Viola!  You now have a (mutually) recursive calculator that can compute anything — it just has to be written in verbose style with parens around everything.

Now stop and admire your code, for at least a day :-)  It's still simple but has the essential recursive nature of parsing.  And the code structure reflects the grammar 1:1 (which is the nice property of recursive descent.  You don't want to know how the other algorithms look).

From here there many improvements possible — support 2+2+2, allow (1), precedence... — but there are 2 ways to go about it:

- Improve your code step by step.  You'll have to refactor a lot.
- Stop working hard and use a parsing library, e.g. [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).
  This will allow you to experiment with grammar changes faster.